# Regex to match addresses of Street 123 format

Tags: java, regex, matching

Streets in Greece have the format Street 123 and I need a Java Regex to match it. The regex I came up with looks correct to me, it's not working though and I am not really an expert on regex. Someone suggested that Java's regex maybe different than Javascripts,and I am not an expert on them either,so can anyone help? I just need a word,followed by 1 whitespace,followed by a 3digit number(max). So for example it should match

- Street 123
- Street 1
- Street 12

but not match `Street123`,`Street1234`,`Street   1234`

Here's my regex:

`ADDRESS_REGEX = "[A-Za-z]+\\s[0-9]{3}+";`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To match a 1-3 digits and a single space:

```
\b[A-Za-z]+\h\d{1,3}\b
```

- `\b` A word boundary
- `[A-Za-z]+` Match 1+ chars A-Za-z
- `\h` Match a horizontal whitspace character
- `\d{1,3}` Match 1-3 digits
- `\b` A word boundary

See a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/ufDgLc/1)

In Java

```
String regex = "\\b[A-Za-z]+\\h\\d{1,3}\\b";
```

Comment: Does the trick,thank you. Can you explain \h a little bit?Ive never seen it before

Comment: @EdwardKoulakidis You are welcome. Using `\h` matches a horizontal whitespace character. There is an explanation on this page about the matches https://www.regular-expressions.info/shorthand.html#more and also on this page https://www.rexegg.com/regex-quickstart.html#whitespace

Answer (score 2):

This version is correct:

```
^[A-Za-z]+\\s[0-9]{1,3}$
```

UPD: sometimes it's better to use `\\h` instead of `\\s` ( because `\\s` also matches with a newline character)

```
^[A-Za-z]+\\h[0-9]{1,3}$
```

So  [The fourth bird's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70631608/10025174) is more correct.